# Rails 3 Routing Error (Namespaced routes help)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Model relationships:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :project_team
  ...
end

class ProjectTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Controller:

```
class Project::TeamController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :projects do
  namespace :project do
    resources :team
  end
end
```

Form code:

```
= form_for @project do |f|
```

When I visit the new Project form, I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"project/team", :project_id=>#<Project id: nil, user_id: 1 ...
```

I've tried many variations of this:

```
= form_for [:project, :team, @project] do |f|
```

To no avail. The routes are just barely off. But, I'm on the new project form, so I'm wondering why it's trying to grab the project team for that anyway.

Thanks for the help! [:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the issue, but to fix it, I just pluralized my controller name.

Answer (score 1):

We should use the nested resources here,

```
resources :projects do
  resource :project_team
end
```

Comment: Well, the way the controller is nested this won't work.

It's nested in a project folder like this:

    class Project::TeamController < ApplicationController

Changed the help post to reflect it.